# Recursive asynchronous JS - how to know when every node is traversed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I have a tree of item (`ul>li`), with potential sub-trees, each node is loaded in ajax on click.

I need a client-side search method, that will open each and every node, and search for the input text. More importantly for this question, the method should display a "loading" panel above the list at the start of the search, and hide the panel when the search is done.

I just can't find a way to know when *all* items have been opened.

The current state is basically this (actual finding of text removed because it's irrelevant to the panel thing) :

```
function displayLoading(node) {
    // returns a created loading panel "attached" to the node
}
function hideLoading(loader) {
    // destroys the loading panel
}

// This is called on page load
function bindDisplay() {
    var tree = $("#tree");

    // initialize: load the root elements
    // -> displays then hides the loading panel just fine
    var loader = displayLoading(tree);
    loadChildren(tree, function () {
        hideLoading(loader);
    });

    // this is where I can't imagine how to handle "my nodes have all been opened"
    var search = function search() {
        var openChildren = function openChildren(ul) {
            ul.find('li').each(function () {
                loadChildren($(this), function (ul) {
                    if (ul && ul.length > 0) {
                        openChildren(ul);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        openChildren(tree);
    };

    $('#searchbutton').on('click', search);
}

function loadChildren(node, callback) {
    // we already know there are no more sub items (see below)
    if (node.data('last') && node.data('last') === true) {
        if (callback) { callback(); }
        return;
    }

    // there already are sub-items that have been loaded once upon a time
    if (node.find('ul').length > 0) {
        if (callback) { callback(node.find('> ul')); }
        return;
    }

    // load children nodes
    var apiUrlGetChildren = $("#tree").data('apigetchildren');
    $.get(apiUrlGetChildren, { id: node.data('id') })
    .done(function (data) {
        // parses data and adds new ul/li to the tree
        // note that I know when there are no sub-items in the loaded items,
        // and in this case I add : newNode.data('last', true)
        var newUl = processData(node);
        node.append(newUl);

        if (callback) { callback(newUl); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Javascript Promises or RxJs extensions can be used  to handle this scenario.

Comment: How ? I can also use events and event listeners, but the main point is : how do I know I have traversed every possible node in the tree ?

Comment: Keeping a global variable with the number of nodes left to process? Increment on start of loadChildren, decrement in the end, once it reaches 0 => you have processed all the children.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev : that's an interesting idea and I will try it, but I'd still like to know if a less "brute force" solution exists...